# News Content - Section, Subsection, Sub-subsection, etc

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Content type "News" in our system can have Sections. Sections can have subsections. Subsections can have sub-subsections, etc. Our authors need the ability to add one or more sections and ability to reorder sections or subsections. I'm new to Drupal so having hard time figuring out how do I go about creating the content type and entry form. Can someone give pointers (modules to look into, books, videos, blogs, etc.) that is similar to my use case?

**Update:**

E.g.:

```
Article Title
 - Section 1
    - subsection 1
    - subsection 2
 - Section 2
    - subsection 1
    - subsection 2
```

The structure of News content type is similar to the structure of a book:

```
Article Title --> book title
 - Section 1  --> chapter title
    - subsection 1  --> section title
    - subsection 2  --> another section title
 - Section 2
    - subsection 1
    - subsection 2
```

- A book can have multiple chapters --> A news article can have many sections
- A chapter can have multiple sections --> A news section can have multiple subsections

Our requirements are similar to the functionality provided by the books module, but the terms "book", "chapter", "page", etc. will confuse our editors; we instead need terms like "Article title", "sections", etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Trying to understand why the question was voted down. Is the question  unclear or need more details? 

PS: I did review different Drupal modules, but I couldn't find how to create the hierarchical content so I posted the question.

Comment: I actually didn't vote it down, just ran into your question, but am struggling to understand what you need myself. Could you give specifics about what you envision? Are these sections other content types that are simply associated with the news, are they *hierarchical tags* that can be applied to news or are they other types of fields?  It would help to know what the final functionality (how does this all work in the end) you're hoping to achieve is in determining the setup/modules that may work best for you. :-)

Comment: @Boriana - thanks for the input. I added more details.

Answer (score 1):

What is a Section?

Assuming that it's another Content Type, you could use [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference).

Practically this means that you would have two Content Types:

- News
- News Section

News Section would have a Node Reference field that can reference both the News & News Section content types.

To create a Section of a News item, you would simply need to create a News Section node, and add the previously created News item to the Node Reference field.

You can go on doing the same whenever you want to add a sub section, except that in that case the reference would be the previously created News Section.

Using Views, it would then be pretty straightforward to call up the various Sections & sub Sections of a News item.